# margin giving wrong output for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to create pivot table with margins.

Sample csv file

```
col1,col2,col3
a,1,z
a,2,z
c,1,x
c,4,x
b,5,y
b,1,y
```

I have create a pivot table using pandas 0.13.1. I am getting correct number for each columns but wrong number for margins.

```
import pandas
import numpy
import re
import math
data = pandas.read_csv('abc.csv');
pivot = pandas.pivot_table(data,values='col1', rows='col2', cols='col3', aggfunc=numpy.count_nonzero, margins=True)
print(pivot)
```

The output that I am getting is

```
col3   x   y   z  All
col2                 
1      1   1   1    6
2    NaN NaN   1    2
4      1 NaN NaN    2
5    NaN   1 NaN    2
All    4   4   4    6
```

Note the counts in All Column and All row are wrong. What is the error in code? How can I get the write summation?

Comment: bizzare!  I don't get that.  I get the correct values.  What version of pandas are you using? `pandas.__version__`

Comment: I am using pandas version 0.13.1

Comment: Apparently there is a bug with pd.cut (or category type fields) + pivot_table. Check this out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582252/pandas-pivot-table-ordered-categories-causing-unexpected-margins