# pandas pivot table - ordered categories causing unexpected margins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Using python 3.7 and pandas 0.23.4. I'm trying to make pivot tables with ordered categorical data. If I include margins, the subtotals don't seem to be in the correct order.

```
import pandas as pd
m='male'
f='female'

data = {'num': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        'age': [1,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,2,3],
        'sex': [f,f,f,f,f,f,f,m,m,m]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df['age1'] = pd.Categorical(df['age'],categories=[3,2,1],ordered=True)
df['sex1'] = pd.Categorical(df['sex'],categories=[m,f],ordered=True)
pd.pivot_table(df,values='num',index='age1',columns='sex1',aggfunc='count',margins=True)
```

Output (incorrect margins order, the 'All' sums are not in the right rows or columns):

```
sex1  male  female  All
age1                   
3        1       4    2
2        1       2    3
1        1       1    5
All      7       3   10
```

Expected output (correct margins order):

```
sex1  male  female  All
age1                   
3        1       4    5
2        1       2    3
1        1       1    2
All      3       7   10
```

In this example it might be better to create the categories with ordered=False. However much of my data is automatically ordered (using pd.cut) so I would like to know if this is intended behavior, and if so, is there a way to remove the ordering on a category that was created with an order?

**Edit**- here's an example using pd.cut. I changed the 'age' column values to appear in reverse of the cut order.

```
import pandas as pd
m='male'
f='female'
data = {'num': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        'age': [3,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,2,3],
        'sex': [f,f,f,f,f,f,f,m,m,m]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['cut'] = pd.cut(df['age'],[1,2,3,4],labels=['<2','2','>2'],right=False)
pd.pivot_table(df,values='num',index='cut',columns='sex',aggfunc='count',margins=True)
```

Output, again with incorrect row margins (corresponding to the ordered category from pd.cut).

```
sex  female  male  All
cut                   
<2        1     1    5
2         2     1    3
>2        4     1    2
All       7     3   10
```

Expected output would be the correct row margin order.

```
sex  female  male  All
cut                   
<2        1     1    2
2         2     1    3
>2        4     1    5
All       7     3   10
```

Comment: This is probably a bug. Maybe you could compute the margins yourself and just append them to the pivoted frame?

Comment: I don't think that the ordering with pd.cut will affect the pivot table aggregate. I think when you pass ordered=True however, that specific argument will cause the error you see.

Comment: @Edeki I have edited my question to include an example with pd.cut that shows the issue.

Comment: @coldspeed that is one option. I would like to continue to use the default pivot table if possible. If the issue is with the ordered categories, I would simply prefer to remove the orderings. If that's not feasible I will not use pd.cut and write my own function to bin data into categories.

Comment: I don't see a difference between the dataframe with pd.cut and your expected answer aside from the index. And once you take into account what they mean that is what I would expect. What is the error you are talking about? Male and Female have the correct aggregates.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I updated the edit so that it's more clear. The ordered category from pd.cut is still causing the pivot table margins to be out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix *For your original question*. Remove the ordered argument from  `df['age1']` and `df['sex1']`

My changes:

```
import pandas as pd
m = 'male'
f = 'female'

data = {'num': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        'age': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        'sex': [f, f, f, f, f, f, f, m, m, m]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df['age1'] = pd.Categorical(df['age'], categories=[3, 2, 1])
df['sex1'] = pd.Categorical(df['sex'], categories=[m, f])
pd.pivot_table(df, values='num', index='age1',
               columns='sex1', aggfunc='count', margins=True)
```

Output:

```
sex  male   female  All
age1            
3     1     4        5
2     1     2        3
1     1     1        2
All   3     7       10
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical):
*Whether or not this categorical is treated as a ordered categorical. If True, the resulting categorical will be ordered. **An ordered categorical respects, when sorted, the order of its categories attribute***

So it looks like when you pass *ordered=True* into pd.Categorical the pivot table will not sort the aggregate based on the category but with the variable appears in your dataframe. If you look at your dataframe, female comes before male so ordered will keep that sort for the aggregate.

**So to answer your question this is the intended behavior of ordered, and you should be careful doing this if you will be sorting your dataframe elsewhere in your script.**